# How to retrieve the CN name of an X509 certificate with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509

I have a number of PEM files for domain certificates. I've already found out how to read the single PEM objects from a file and I can tell apart certificates from private keys. Now I need to know the subject name for each certificate I find. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist any documentation and I wasn't able to find other users on the web who talked about doing this. Most code that I found was about Java and used names that are not available in the current library (for C# at least). Whether it's an exotic task to read CN values from a certificate or not, I need to do it.

Here's what I found so far:

Install the NuGet package Portable.BouncyCastle 1.8.8

```cs
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("cert.pem"))
{
    var pemReader = new PemReader(streamReader);
    while (true)
    {
        object pemObject = pemReader.ReadObject();
        if (pemObject == null)
            break;
        switch (pemObject)
        {
            case RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey:
                Console.WriteLine("Private key");
                break;
            case X509Certificate certificate:
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate");
                // This has ALL entries from the subject, including CN
                Console.WriteLine("  Subject: " + certificate.SubjectDN);

                // This is a convoluted list of lists of lists of stuff that seems to contain
                // the CN values somewhere deep within but I can't figure out how to access it
                var derSequence = certificate.SubjectDN.ToAsn1Object() as DerSequence;
                // And I'm not sure if these are the correct types to use and what other
                // types to be prepared for in real life.

                // Like the below untyped list of untyped lists of stuff seems to be working
                // to extract the alternative names (SAN) from a certificate:
                var altNames = certificate.GetSubjectAlternativeNames()?
                    .OfType<System.Collections.ArrayList>()
                    .SelectMany(l => l.OfType<string>())
                    .ToList();
                if (altNames != null)
                {
                    foreach (string str in altNames)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  Subject alternative name: " + str);
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If BouncyCastle is the wrong tool and I should use a .NET-integrated class (.NET Core 3.1 or 5.0), please let me know and explain that instead. I also need other data like the time a certificate was issued or expires.

Here's the workaround I'm using for now. It's probably a very dowdy method for a thing as complex as X509. But that's the level I understand from it.

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(certificate.SubjectDN.ToString(), @"(?:^|,)CN=([^,]+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Subject: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: I think it's there. Bouncycastle has classes in the `x509` directory like `x509.X509Certificate` that handle certificates. That class has a property `SubjectDN` that can be examined for the CN and other components of the Subject name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track with your approch on the `SubjectDN` member.

Here is a one-liner working example extracting the `CN=` using Linq and BouncyCastle (it defaults to empty string if there is no CN=name in the subject):

```
certificate.SubjectDN.GetValueList(X509Name.CN).Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist any documentation

I really doubt in this statement. .NET has built-in functionality to work with certificates: [X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-5.0) class.

And here how the code would look like to get CN (when present. If not present, then most suitable RDN attribute or subject alternative name is returned):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; // ref namespace

//
var cert = new X509Certificate2("cert.pem");
Console.WriteLine("  Subject: " + cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, false));
```

For certificate validity or other data, please explore [X509Certificate2 properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-5.0#properties).

Comment: So you're saying that BouncyCastle is the wrong tool for this, do I understand this correctly? You didn't mention it, so I might assume you don't know what BouncyCastle is. It's used by another library that deals with certificates (Certes) so I thought I could reuse it here. – But your solution doesn't work anyway. That class always reports it cannot find the file while BouncyCastle can read it just fine.

Comment: I'm saying that BC is an unnecessary dependency for such trivial task. As of file not found -- means that file does not exist in specified folder. If you specify relative path, it is relative to working directory (by default, where executable resides). If you have difficulties with X509Certificate2, please update your question with relevant code and errors you face.

Comment: Must take into account that `X509Certificate2` is probably one of the worst classes to work with, in the whole .NET system.. and in contrast Bouncycastle is a pleasure to work with.

Comment: @JB.WithMonica. I totally disagree with you.

Comment: Opinions are not as useful as helpful facts.

Comment: code worked like a charm, no need for yet another dependency or breaking the law of demeters  :)

Comment: Thanks - this just worked!  Very good answer.